# Event Listener Help (making one button/element do multiple things)

Tags: javascript, events

Hi I have this issue where I cant get more than one event from my code.

the goal is to have this display both functions in order....any help would be awesome!!!

```
var button = document.getElementById("button element");
//only clicks once:
button.addEventListener("click", function, false);
button.addEventListener("click", function2, false);
```

Comment: to be more specific I need to be able to click the button once and run that code, then again and run a different set of code.

Comment: dont use the keyword function as your function name  as the word "function" itself is a reserved keyword in javacript. Try with some other names other than saying function and function2.

Comment: @user2793657: To improve/clarify your question, use the "edit" link, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the handler triggered by a click to change, you change the handler:

```
function firstThing() {
    // Do something

    // Set up next handler
    this.removeEventListener("click", firstThing, false);
    this.addEventListener("click", nextThing, false);
}

function nextThing() { /* .... */ }

button.addEventListener("click", firstThing, false);
```

Or more simply, just keep track of the state:

```
var clicked = false;
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!clicked) {
        // Do the first thing
        clicked = true;
    }
    else {
        // Do the next thing
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: can you do this with 3 items??

Comment: @user2793657: Replace the boolean flag with a counter.